# Importing files from Unix to MS SQL Server

Tags: windows, unix, import, sql-server-2008-r2

We need to copy large amounts of data (approx 1 GB) from an Oracle database on a UNIX server into tables in MS SQL Server 2008 r2 (running on a Windows server).  This task will be repeated on a regular basis, not just a one-time job.

We have the code to export the data to text files, but the files are generated on the UNIX server.

We have the code to import the text files (bulk insert), but this only seems to work when the files are on a Windows server (bulk insert needs UNC).

Physically copying the files is resource intensive.  It would be far better to write them once and read them once.

What's the best way to do this?  Is there a way for Oracle to write the files onto a Windows network location?  Is there a way for MS SQL Server 2008 r2 to read text files from a UNIX server?  Is there another method entirely?

Comment: Andy, if you don't get a response here, this sounds more like a question for the DBA site, dba.stackexchange.com You may get an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for Oracle to write the files onto a Windows network location? Is there a way for MS SQL Server 2008 r2 to read text files from a UNIX server?

Yes, it is called [Samba](https://www.samba.org/).

> Is there another method entirely?

[Create](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/) a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). This will allow your SQL Server to query your Oracle server and fetch the data without saving it to files at all.

To create the linked server, you must install [Oracle Data Access Components](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/) on the SQL Server. Then you must configure Oracle OleDB provider to run inside SQL Server process and to accept parameters:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
exec master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'DynamicParameters', 1
```

Then create the linked server definition:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver N'MyOracle', 'Oracle', 'ORAOLEDB.Oracle', N'//1.2.3.4/xe', N'FetchSize=2000', ''
exec master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyOracle', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='MyOracle', @useself=N'FALSE', @rmtuser=N'system', @rmtpassword='xxxxxx'
```

And if everything is configured properly, you can query the Oracle server directly:

```
exec ('select 1 a from dual') at MyOracle
```